# 2D Array Overwritten When It Shouldn't Be

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I'm writing some code that reads input from a file.

My code parses the input file's contents and stores the data as a 2D array, e.g.

The input is (please see input file below for correct formatting, I can't get the formatting to work here):

---

ABC

DEF

G

---

After parsing the 2D array should look like this...
[['A','B','C',],['D','E','F'],['G']]

The problem I have is that somehow the previous elements are being written over in the 2D array with subsequent entries, e.g.

[['G'],['G'],['G']]

I've looked through it but can't see how this is happening, as writes to the 2D array should only occur once per new entry, and then they should only happen with appending the new data to the 2D array, and not overwrite previous entries.

I'm a bit stuck, do any of you have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Thanks!:)

## Code

```
    class Reader

    def initialize
        @command_array = Array.new { Array.new } # 2D array

    end

      def run(file)
        return puts "please provide correct file" if file.nil? || !File.exists?(file)

        command_line = Array.new            #Temp array
        p "----------------------------------------------------------------"
        File.open(file).each do |line|     
          p "looking at a line of commands..."
          line.split(' ').each do |command| 
            p "storing the command #{command} in temp array"
            command_line.push(command)
            p command_line
          end

          p "Storing the temp array as an element in the 2d array..."
          @command_array.push(command_line)
          p @command_array

          p "Clearing the temp array..."
          p "----------------------------------------------------------------"
          command_line.clear
        end
      end
    end
```

#

## Input File

```
A B C
D E F
G
```

#

## Output

```
    "looking at a line of commands..."
    "storing the command A in temp array"
    ["A"]
    "storing the command B in temp array"
    ["A", "B"]
    "storing the command C in temp array"
    ["A", "B", "C"]
    "Storing the temp array as an element in the 2d array..."
    [["A", "B", "C"]]
    "Clearing the temp array..."
    "----------------------------------------------------------------"
    "looking at a line of commands..."
    "storing the command D in temp array"
    ["D"]
    "storing the command E in temp array"
    ["D", "E"]
    "storing the command F in temp array"
    ["D", "E", "F"]
    "Storing the temp array as an element in the 2d array..."
    [["D", "E", "F"], ["D", "E", "F"]]
    "Clearing the temp array..."
    "----------------------------------------------------------------"
    "looking at a line of commands..."
    "storing the command G in temp array"
    ["G"]
    "Storing the temp array as an element in the 2d array..."
    [["G"], ["G"], ["G"]]
    "Clearing the temp array..."
```

#

Comment: `p x` is intended to be used for debugging, it's the equivalent of `puts x.inspect`. You should be displaying prompts with `puts`, that avoids the quotes.

Comment: Hey @tadman, thanks for your input. I was just using 'p' as a quick way to throw the contents of the arrays to screen. Thanks again for looking at this:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you've gone out of your way to recycle the same array for each line you parse. Remember in Ruby that `Array#push` puts an object reference (pointer) to the array you're pushing so any modifications to that object will impact all references to it.

A more minimal form of your program is:

```
class Reader
  def initialize
    @command_array = [ ]
  end

  def run(file)
    @command_array = File.readlines(file).map do |line|
      line.chomp.split(' ')
    end
  end
end
```

Your initial assignment to `Array.new { Array.new }` isn't really useful, the second argument is the default which is never used since you only `push` things into it. There's no need in Ruby to strongly type things this way. An array is just an array, a hash is just a hash, they don't need to be initialized in any particular form to be used in any particular fashion. `array[0]['hash_key']` can be valid at the same time as `array[1][2]` on the same object.

Whenever you're having problems with objects behaving like clones, where they're somehow *entangled* and changes to one impact others, you're probably using the same object inadvertently. To see what Ruby perceives your array as use:

```
p @command_array.map(&:object_id)
```

Which will show which object identifiers are in there. In your case they'd all be identical.

Comment: Hey again @tadman. Great answer:) What you mention with the pointers makes complete sense now. I thought each iteration of storing the 'command' variable would be stored in a separate location in memory in the 'command_array', which it doesn't, just the pointer to the data's source.

The 'p @command_array.map(&:object_id)' line of code is really useful too, I'll be sure to use it again. Must remember all this stuff sits somewhere in memory when called;) Thanks again, a really informative and well articulated answer!:)